# If A denotes the union of these cosets formed by the elements of a subgroup of the quotient group H, show that A is a subgroup of G.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm having trouble with this problem.

Comment: The elements of $G/N$ are cosets of $N$ in $G$. Because $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, its elements are also cosets of $N$ in $G$, but _not necessarily all_ cosets of $N$ in $G$. So the approach you suggest is _not_ right.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Now I have no clue;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that

$$A:=\{x\in G\;:\;xN\in H(\le G/N)\}\le G$$

For example:

$$H\le G/N\implies\;\text{the unit of the quotient is in}\;\;H\implies 1N=N\in H\implies 1\in A$$

$$x,y\in A\implies xN,yN\in H\implies xNyN:=(xy)N\in H\implies xy\in A$$

Can you take it from here? And you can do more: show that

$$\;H\lhd G/N\iff A\lhd G\;\;,\;\;\text{and also}\;\;[G/N:H]=[G:A]$$

The above is the wonderful and very helpful Correspondence Theorem for groups.

Comment: Sorry can you explain it a bit more? I'm still a little bit lost.

Comment: Did you read carefully the above? There's already proved $\;A\;$ contains the group's unit and is closed under the product operation of it. You still need to show every element in $\;A\;$ has an inverse **in** $\;A\;$ , and associativity...The last parts you don't need, of course, to do them. That was from me.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question, what do you mean by xN?

Comment: The left coset $\;xN\;$ (and element of) in the quotient group $\;G/N\;$ ...

Comment: Thank you! Could you show me how to prove the inverse is in A? Thanks so much!!